# Возможна ли конвертация кодека mpga в другой в Swift(e)?

Tags: swift, аудио

У меня в приложении некоторые видео с кодеком MPEG Audio layer 1/2 (mpga) и в таких видео нет звука. По всей видимости, нет поддержки такого кодека у Apple.
От сюда встает вопрос: можно ли этот кодек конвертировать в другой, который поддерживает Apple?

Comment: https://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-macosx.ru.html

Comment: @AlexanderChernin, т.е. если использовать VLC плеер, то этот кодек будет воспроизводиться в моем приложении?

Comment: Да, при установке все нужное должно подтянуться